# Problem getting modal to display from GridView event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Before anyone says it, I have tried all of the examples I can find, and nothing seems to work so far, so that's why I'm posting a new question.

I am working on an ASP.NET web forms project, and I have a page containing a GridView control that has several command buttons for each record representing different options.  One of them is "Subscriptions", which I want to use to display details of a subscription record in a Bootstrap modal dialog.  I stripped the modal dialog code down to the bare minimum:

```
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubscriptionPopUp" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <div id="SubscriptionPopUp" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Subscription Details</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button id="Button1" runat="server" onclick="btnCancel_Click" cssclass="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
                            <button id="btnClose" class="btn btn-success">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Here is the JavaScript code I'm using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SubscriptionPopUp").modal("show");

            $("#btnClose").click(function () {
                $("#SubscriptionPopUp").modal("hide");
            });
        });
        function ShowStatus() {
            console.log("got here!");
            $("#SubscriptionPopUp").modal("show");
        }

    </script>
```

Now, when I click the button in the GridView, it fires the RowCommand event just fine, and here is the code I included to register and call the client-side script:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript ( this.Page, this.GetType ( ), "ShowSubscriptionStatus", "ShowStatus();", true );
```

So, all of the code fires, and if you notice, I instrumented the JavaScript function to log a message, which does work.  Problem is, the modal form never appears.  There are no errors or messages of any kind in the console, no debugging errors...nothing.

I am stumped as to why this isn't firing properly, or why I at least am not getting any kind of error messages.

Comment: Is ````pnlSubscriptionPopUp```` ever set to ````Visible = True```` ?  It might be better to have it set default to ````True```` and then in code-behind set to ````False```` if needed.

Comment: If I set it to true on the initial page load, it shows up.  Subsequent actions don't do anything.

Comment: "If I set it to true on the initial page load, it shows up" -- if you have ````pnlSubscriptionPopUp```` set to True the modal is auto-popped open on initial load? Or you mean the JS function works to pop the modal after button click on initial load, but then won't work again after that?

Comment: It opens the modal on initial load (the script in the $(document) function does), but when I try to load it any other time it does nothing.  I get no messages in the console at all

Comment: Can you debug in the browser? Set a breakpoint on your ````ShowStatus()```` and see if it's even being hit.

Comment: ShowStatus is hit, and it prints the console message I have in there.  But the modal itself never appears, and there are no other messages of any kind.  A "silent fail" with no way to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, having done this many times?

I really like bootstrap for many things. However, for dialogs, I jumped over to jQuery.UI.

I find a wee bit too much markup an adding of this class and that class to make such dialogs work.

You have a REALLY nice answer below – (I up voted that answer).

I also try to avoid document “ready” code (unless I have to – it’s always hard to debug).

However, I find jQuery.UI is just simple “div” that you drop on the page (display:none to hide). And that’s it!

So, let’s assume we have a grid, click a row, and we want to show that row data in that div.

So, our grid is like this:

```
  <div style="width:40%">

      <asp:GridView ID="MyGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" 
          DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
          OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" >

        <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Porvince" />


            <asp:Templatefield HeaderText ="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View"
                        CommandName = "Select"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Templatefield>
        </Columns>
    
      </asp:GridView>
```

Nothing fancy.
NOTE: I did not use templated fields. If you do, then you have to use find control in place of the "easy for this example" .cells collection.

so, so above is the markup.

Here is our code to load up above:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 12 * from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            MyGrid.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            MyGrid.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Ok, so far so very good.

We thus have this now:

[image]

Now lets add our pop div.

```
  <div id="mypop" style="display:none">
          <br />
          <div style="text-align:right">

            <p>Hotel Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>Last Name:<asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>City:<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
            <p>Province:<asp:TextBox ID="txtProvince" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>

           </div>

        </div>
```

Again, nice - JUST SIMPLE and NICE plane jane div and that's going to be our popup.
(and note how we don't have a gazzllion class and settings - just oh so nice and simple).

Now, that button has the "magic" CommandName = "Select", so that WILL trigger the Selected index change event.

So, our code in that to pop the dialog is this:

```
    protected void MyGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // fill out dialog boxes
        GridViewRow dG = MyGrid.SelectedRow;

        txtFirst.Text = dG.Cells[0].Text;
        txtLast.Text = dG.Cells[1].Text; ;
        txtHotel.Text = dG.Cells[2].Text; ;
        txtCity.Text = dG.Cells[3].Text; ;
        txtProvince.Text = dG.Cells[4].Text; ;

        // call our js routine to pop
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(),"my test","poptest()", true);

    }
```

And last but not lest, the jQuery.UI pop routine that above calls.

```
     <script>

            function poptest() {
                var mydiv = $('#mypop')
                mydiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Hotel Information', width: '400px',
                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                    closeText: '',
                    buttons: {
                        'ok': function () {
                            // $('#cmdAdd').click() - click standard asp button
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                        },
                        'cancel': function () {
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Open the dialog
                // mydiv.parent().appendTo($("form:first")) - only add if editing in div
                mydiv.dialog('open')
            }
        </script>
```

Now the nice bonus in above is we have two buttons - and i show how to close the dialog - but we can also call/click say a button on the form to run code based on either choice (I do suggest setting for those buttons ClientIDMode="Static", and thus the VERY easy code above for the ok or cancel can thus just "click()" that button. That way you don't have to do fancy foot work to call code based on the choice.

When the dialog pops, it automatic turns the rest of the page "shaded" out, and all other controls except for the dialog are enabled.

Now, the results thus look like this:

[image]

As you can see, we get a LOT of bang for the efforts here. A simple div is turned into that rather nice dialog. And we have a simple set of buttons that are part of the dialog that can then do actions based on what you click on those buttons that the dialog has support for.

I do somewhat apologize for suggesting a different road. I found the jQuery.UI dialog just works, is really easy. If someone would just build a cute little library to use simple divs with bootstrap dialogs - sign me up! - but I found just too many "issues" in trying to get the bootstrap dialogs to work. This may well be my shortcomings - but often a simple approach with just a simple div + the jQuery.UI dialog works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example that I wrote which will hopefully give you some insight on how you can fix yours, as I don't really know your GridView setup.  Though potentially just adding `document.ready()` to your `ShowStatus()` might fix this issue.

Front-End

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="headcontent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowStatus() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#SubscriptionPopUp").modal("show");
            })
        }

        function closeModal(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#SubscriptionPopUp").modal("hide");
            return false;  // don't want a post back
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvTest_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvTest_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnShowSubscription" runat="server" CommandName="Subscription" Text="Show Subscription Data" />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


    <div id="SubscriptionPopUp" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Subscription Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTestOutput" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="btnClose" onclick="closeModal(event)" class="btn btn-success">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code-Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<String> names = new List<string>() { "Kobe", "Jordan", "Wilt" };
        gvTest.DataSource = names;
        gvTest.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btnShowSubscription = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnShowSubscription");
        if (btnShowSubscription != null)
        {
            // usually if my DataItem is an object, I'll cast it first and make sure it's not null
            btnShowSubscription.CommandArgument = (string)e.Row.DataItem;
        }
    }
}

protected void gvTest_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.Equals(e.CommandName, "Subscription"))
    {
        // again, probably cast this and do a !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() check
        switch ((string)e.CommandArgument)
        {
            case "Kobe":
                this.lblTestOutput.Text = "Kobe is the best";
                break;
            case "Wilt":
                this.lblTestOutput.Text = "Wilt is the best";
                break;
            case "Jordan":
                this.lblTestOutput.Text = "Jordan is the best";
                break;
        }

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(string), "ShowSubscriptionStatus", "ShowStatus();", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an "Uncaught Reference Error, ShowStatus is not defined" error.

Comment: And your script that houses the ````ShowStatus()```` is on the page?

Comment: As you'll see on my example,. the ````ShowStatus()```` is in the header.  And you don't have any ````UpdatePanels```` do you?

Comment: Looks like you may have went the jQuery UI dialog path.  Hope that works!  Good luck